JSF 3.0: How to set conditional navigation?
I got a problem in the authentication part of my website written in jakarta ee 9, jsf 3.0. It's about conditional navigation. When trying to access /result.xhtml, I get the login page to check if I have the necessary autorisations to access the resource, when successful login I am not redirected to /result.xhtml, instead I need to refresh the /result.xhtml page.
In my managed bean loginBean, I tried to set up a conditional navigation :

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String pageId;

    // Getters and setters for username and password

    public String login() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        String viewId = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(viewId);
        setPageId(viewId);
        try {
            request.login(this.username, this.password);
            if (pageId.contains("result")){
                return "result?faces-redirect=true";
            } else if (pageId.contains("processorders")) {
                return "processorders?faces-redirect=true";
            }else{
                return "index?faces-redirect=true";
            }

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login failed."));
            return "Error";
        }

    }

But I always get the /index.xhtml page, which means the uri is not properly retrieved? May I have missed something?
